# Report Viewer Control Causing Program Not To Start

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I am having a very strange problem. I developed a program for my client, which is being installed in his computer and 2 other computers in his office, I deploy it by simply copying the files from the project release folder into a folder on the clients computer.

Lately, when I added a report viewer control and a report file to the program, something happened, the program runs fine on one computer, but on the other 2 computers the program refuses to launch, it doesn't display any warning or error massage, it just doesn't start, clicking on the .exe file does nothing. When I remove the report viewer control and rebuild the solution everything runs fine on all computers, why is this happening, please help.

I am using windows 7, VS 2015 Community edition. All the computers for running the program are windows 10.

Comment: Is there any error being reported in EventViewer?

Comment: i will take a look and report back